# Understanding HTML Purifier

Tags: php, codeigniter, security, xss

I am currently using CodeIgniter. I have 4 forms (student signin, login in form, create account, and request account)

I am currently using this at the moment to filter my input on one of the forms (create account) :

```
function create()
    {
        $this->load->library('bcrypt'); 
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('fname', 'First Name', 'trim|required|alpha|max_length[14]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('lname', 'Last Name', 'trim|required|alpha|max_length[14]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email Address', 'trim|required|is_unique[users.email]|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|is_unique[users.username]|required|alpha_numeric||min_length[4]|max_length[15]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[7]|alpha_dash|max_length[20]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('passwordconf', 'Confirm Password', 'trim|required|min_length[7]|max_length[20]|matches[password]|alpha_dash');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->view();
        }
```

To my understand HTML Purifier should be only used when user data is going to be echo'd/outputted as HTML in a table, forum, blog (etc.) Is my understanding of this correct? I am asking because my student login form will be used to enter data into a database. Then my student queue page will be used to SELECT ... FROM ... that database. So this is confusing me as when I create the output for the student queue the data will be database housed. it wont just be posted directly.

So in turn my train of thought goes as follows :

- Validate data making sure it is what you expect
- Filter the data with xss_clean like I currently am.
- Use PDO prepared queries to insert the data to the DB
- (now this step confuses me)  How I should echo my database data?
  should i use HTML Purifier at this step?

Sorry if this question has been asked a million times, I just can't seem to find what I am looking for. I am not fully gripping the concept of HTML purifier.

Edit 1 : Using the global xss_clean filter in the config file.

Comment: If the data contains HTML code submitted by the user - yes

Comment: Right, it shouldn't have html or script in it. I am only going to be allowing aplha_numberic characters.

Comment: Then you don't need the purifier. Just [filter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php) the fields and make sure they contain only A-Z, 0-9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML Purifier is for when you have a string whose datatype is HTML and you want to restrict the kinds of HTML that may appear in it.

However none of the fields you have here are HTML--they are all just strings. So to display them you simply escape the strings for display in HTML, like you would for any string.

More recent versions of CodeIgniter have a `html_escape()` function. Use it in your views like so:

```
<p><?=html_escape($mystring)?></p>
```

If you are using an older version, use `htmlspecialchars($mystring, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'utf-8')` directly. You should probably wrap this in a one-argument function.

Comment: thank you so much. I just got the same answer from one of the guys over at the htmlpurifier.org thanks a lot man.